# Is there a way to allow the public to view a document library?

Tags: 2013, document-library, public-website, records-management

I was wondering if there is a way, as a small business, to share your public records with the entire public, meaning that anyone can read/download them without logging in. More specifically I have an Office 365 E3 account using Sharepoint online. I have not been able to find a solution to this , while some people say it is impossible I figure there has to be a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this post I found gives some info on public-facing Sharepoint sites: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3027254/sharepoint-online-public-websites-to-be-discontinued